# The expired sms code immediately after receiving the sms

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have an application that you can log in to by phone number

After entering the phone number I receive an SMS code

A new screen opens where I can enter this code

When I enter the code, I get information that the code is expired

**Sign:** First screen

```
  onSignIn() {
    const {code, phoneNumber} = this.state;
    const newNumber = '+' + code + phoneNumber;
    if (newNumber.length > 10) {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(newNumber)
        .then(confirmResult => {
          this.setState({result: confirmResult});
          const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: 'SecurityCode',
            params: {phoneAuthResponse: confirmResult},
          });
          this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.message === 'TOO SHORT') {
            alert('Please enter a valid phone number');
          } else {
            alert(error.message);
          }
        });
    } else {
      alert('Please Enter Your Number');
    }
  }
```

**Confirm:** Second screen

```
  onConfirmCode() {
    const {securityCode} = this.state;
    if (securityCode.length > 5) {
      this.props.navigation.state.params.phoneAuthResponse
        .confirm(securityCode)
        .then(async user => {
          const ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${user.uid}`);
          ref.once('value', async snapshot => {
            let data = snapshot.val();
            if (!data) {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('CreateProfile', {
                user: {uid: user.uid, phone_number: user.phoneNumber},
              });
            } else {
              this.props.reduxLoginUser(data);
              this.props.navigation.navigate('InviteContacts');
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error.message));
    } else {
      alert('Please enter the 6 digit code');
    }
  }
```

What is done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user has been created (You can do this on the Firebase project page)

If it is created then there is another problem to be solved

**You must catch that the user is created and go to the screen after logging in**